# Perl Regular Expression

Tags: regex, perl

Need help with a regular expression to replace

```
"CALLID = DB4EC1F310000134255A83470A7B6A4B ID = DB..."
```

with

```
"CALLID = <a>DB4EC1F310000134255A83470A7B6A4B</a> ID = DB..."
```

Comment: Is the string that looks like a hex string fixed or variable length? Is it a hex string?

Comment: It could be of variable length. Yes its a hex string.

Comment: Why negative vote, is it too simple or my question is wrong ?

Comment: Generally they are a result of you saying you need help with a regular expression and ask people to code it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
(?<=CALLID = )(\S+)
```

and replace with

```
<a>$1</a>
```

In Perl

```
my $s = "CALLID = DB4EC1F310000134255A83470A7B6A4B ID = DB...";
$s =~ s/(?<=CALLID = )(\S+)/<a>$1<\/a>/;
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2voba)

`(?<=CALLID = )` is a lookbehind assertion, it ensures that `CALLID =` is before the pattern you want to replace.

`(\S+)` is matching a series of at least one non whitespace characters and store it in `$1`, because of the brackets around it.

Comment: Could also use `\K`, like `s/CALLID = \K(\S+)/<a>$1<\/a>/`.

Comment: @Qtax thanks for introducing something new to me. Never heard of `\K` before! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

```
s#(CALLID = )(\S+)#$1<a>$2</a>#
```

what it means.  I've used `#` as the regexp delimiter instead of `/` so no escaping is required when a `/` is used in the output

`( )` are grouping the catches as `$1`, `$2`

`\S+` means "one character or more of non white space"

after the second `#` it's the rewrite of the matched section

Comment: +1 for showing how to do without lookbehind and for the different delimiters.

Comment: and nice first answer, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this, this will handle variation in space, and only catch hex in $2.

```
my $s = "CALLID = DB4EC1F310000134255A83470A7B6A4B ID = DB..."
$s =~ s#(CALLID[=\s]+)([A-Fa-f01-9]+)#$1<a>$2</a>#gis;
```

One liner test:

`perl -e 'my $s = "CALLID = DB4EC1F310000134255A83470A7B6A4B ID = DB...";$s =~ s#(CALLID[=\s]+)([A-Fa-f01-9]+)#$1<a>$2</a>#gis;print "s: $s\n";'`

Comment: `..` is not the syntax for ranges in regex, you want `-` instead, like `[A-F\d]+`.